# Parallel execution of a loop that uses async

Tags: c#, asynchronous, concurrency, parallel-processing, async-await

I'm writing a Windows service and am looking for a way to execute a number of foreach loops in parallel, where each loop makes a call to an asynchronous (TAP) method. I initially tried the following code, which doesn't work because Parallel.ForEach and async/await are not compatible. Does anyone know whether there is an alternate approach that can achieve this?

```
Parallel.ForEach(messagesByFromNumber, async messageGroup =>
{
    foreach (var message in messageGroup)
    {
        await message.SendAsync();
    }
});
```

For the sake of clarity, due to the way that SendAsync() operates, each copy of the foreach loop must execute serially; in other words, the foreach loop cannot become concurrent / parallel.

Comment: I'm not entirely convinced you would need the parallel at all since the async call is a fire and forget type method.  Just do a standard for each and fire the async method should do something very close to what you want it to do

Comment: @theDarse The reason I couldn't use a standard foreach as the outer loop is because the SendAsync() method is so slow that I needed the outer loop to have the chance to run on separate threads. Doing two nested standard foreach loops would take too long.

Comment: Don't mix parallel and async code. Use async when you don't want to burn a thread (usually I/O calls), Parallel is for CPU intensive calculations to execute on all cores in parallel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no need to use `Parallel.Foreach` if your goal is to run these concurrently. Simply go over all your groups, create a task for each group that does a `foreach` of `SendAsync`, get all the tasks, and `await` them all at once with `Task.WhenAll`:

```
var tasks = messagesByFromNumber.Select(async messageGroup =>
{
    foreach (var message in messageGroup)
    {
        await message.SendAsync();
    }
});
await Task.WhenAll(tasks)
```

Comment: I had no idea that async could be used in the select statement that way. Just tried your solution and the code ran as desired. Thanks so much!

Comment: @JeffGlazier sure... any time.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it more cleat with [AsyncEnumerator NuGet Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AsyncEnumerator/1.1.0):

```
using System.Collections.Async;

await messagesByFromNumber.ParallelForEachAsync(async messageGroup =>
{
    foreach (var message in messageGroup)
    {
        await message.SendAsync();
    }
}, maxDegreeOfParallelism: 10);
```